# MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: when using ydata_profiling

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas-profiling

**pandas_profiling** is deprecated and now  need to use '**ydata-profiling**' instead ([pandas-profiling](https://pypi.org/project/pandas-profiling/)). When using ydata-profiling, following warning arises when saving profile report to a html file.

*MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: mplDeprecation was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.6 and will be removed two minor releases later. Use matplotlib.MatplotlibDeprecationWarning instead*

Warning arises in
*File ~\anaconda3\envs\spe\lib\site-packages\ydata_profiling\visualisation\context.py:85, in manage_matplotlib_context()

83 deregister_matplotlib_converters()  # revert to original unit registries

84 with warnings.catch_warnings():

---> 85     warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=**matplotlib.cbook.mplDeprecation**)

86     matplotlib.rcParams.update(originalRcParams)*

I'm using following code to create the profile report for the data frame called 'df',

```
import pandas as pd
from ydata_profiling import ProfileReport

# generate pandas_profiling reports
report = ProfileReport(df,
                   sample = None,
                   missing_diagrams = None,
                   duplicates = None,
                   interactions = None,
                   title="Correlation Comparison",
                   correlations={"pearson": {"calculate": True},
                                 "spearman": {"calculate": True},
                                 "kendall": {"calculate": True},
                                 "phi_k": {"calculate": True},
                                 "auto": {"calculate": False},
                                 })
# create the output file paths
html_file_name = report_name + '.html'

file_path_to_html = os.path.join( os.getcwd(), html_file_name)

report.to_file(file_path_to_html)
```

I tried following in my notebook:

```
import warnings
import matplotlib
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore",category=matplotlib.MatplotlibDeprecationWarning)
```

But still the warning is there and code is not working!!!

I'm using following ydata_profiling and matplotlib versions,
*ydata_profiling == v4.5.1

matplotlib == 3.7.3*

Comment: What is your matplotlib version ? Also please provide a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: personally, although it is allowable, i would not ignore warnings...

Comment: @Goku Apologies for the insufficient details. I'm using matplotlib == 3.7.3. And I've added a minimum reproducible example. Thank you!!